# Tenho uma dúvida: no caso da multiplicação de vetores, por que tenho que iniciar com {0}? E por que 3 for?

Tags: javascript, c, array, typescript, matriz

No caso do **{0}**, eu entendo que é por causa da inicialização de todos os elementos com zero. Mas o que não me entra na cabeça é que **{0}** não é um objeto em C. Eu uso normalmente JavaScript ou TypeScript, e para mim isso seria um objeto. Alguém poderia me explicar?

E se a chave serve de fato para inicializar arrays e matrizes com valores específicos, por que ela é usada dessa forma? Queria entender mais sobre isso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// 10. Fazer um algoritmo que leia os valores de duas
// matrizes 3×3 e imprima a multiplicação das duas matrizes.
#define TAMANHO  3

int main() {
  int array1[TAMANHO][TAMANHO];
  int array2[TAMANHO][TAMANHO];
  int array[TAMANHO][TAMANHO] = {0};

  // Leitura da matriz array1
  for (size_t l = 0; l < TAMANHO; l++) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < TAMANHO; c++) {
      scanf("%d", &array1[l][c]);
    }
  }

  // Leitura da matriz array2
  for (size_t l = 0; l < TAMANHO; l++) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < TAMANHO; c++) {
      scanf("%d", &array2[l][c]);
    }
  }

  // Multiplicação das matrizes
  for (int l = 0; l < TAMANHO; l++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < TAMANHO; c++) {
      for (int z = 0; z < TAMANHO; z++) {
        array[l][c] += array1[l][z] * array2[z][c];
      }
    }
  }

  // Impressão da matriz resultante
  for (size_t l = 0; l < TAMANHO; l++) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < TAMANHO; c++) {
      printf("%d ", array[l][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual a relação de C com JS e TypeScript no seu código? Qual o objetivo do código?